# How to swap between traditional and LDAP authentication?

Tags: ldap, openldap, debian-wheezy

I have a Debian wheezy configured for LDAP authentication (with OpenLDAP). Is there a way to go back to traditional authetication (not LDAP)?

Adding LDAP involved running a wizard so I don't know which configuration files were modified...

Comment: Have you confirmed that non-ldap authentication (`pam_unix`) isn't working?

Comment: I did this: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_7.0&p=ldap&f=2 and I don't know how to undo.